# Could not allocate a new page for database because of insufficient disk space in filegroup

Tags: sql-server, compiler-errors, sas

while running a program in SAS conected to SQL-server 2008 I am getting this ERROR in the log:

> Execute error: ICommand::Execute failed. : The statement has been terminated.: 
>              Could not allocate a new page for database 'databse' because of insufficient disk space in 
>           filegroup 'CURRENT01'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, 
>           adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in 
>           the filegroup.

I am looking to similar problems and I can not really see the solution. 
I am quite sure we have enough space in the database.
is it maybe anything related with the work? I am quite new with SQL server.

Thank you, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Errors like this, your database is taking disk space and not the space available to DB, this happens when you are doing bulk Insert operation (Mostly).

You can see it by clicking  the `database -> Properties -> Files -> Database - space available and size`.

Try Dropping some tables and then release the space.

Answer (score 9):

Check the settings of data file(s) in that file group. Most likely their upper size limit is capped in which case it does not matter if you have free space.

You can find these settings with Management Studio: right click the database -> Properties -> Files -> Column Autogrowth/Max Size.

You should also check that the database files are on the disk drive where you expect them to be.

Comment: It is set to none. What should I choose?

Comment: @yke: There is no none option :). Just click the ellipsis button in that column and set the options as you need them (file growth and maximum file size). You shouldn't set them to random values. Maybe you can cross check that with your sysadmin or DBA before you make any changes.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much. I do not have the rights to set it but I will request the change. :)